# Show applications of current workspace in dock and not from other workspaces

Tags: macos, dock

One thing I miss about XFCE was the ability to show which applications were open in the current workspace. Is it possible to have the opened applications of the current workspace indicate in the dock? I have tried using [Contexts](https://contexts.co/), but after a few hours, it's buggy.

[Video of me explaining my question if what I wrote did not make sense.](https://streamable.com/8xcg2)